# Using Functions and Arrays to Read and Print Data from a File

Tags: c++, arrays, file, function

I'm relatively new to C++ and my professor gave us an assignment that I can't seem to figure out.

We are supposed to write functions that can read a file and print the values to a screen. We're then supposed to be able to print out the largest value from the file. It sounds simple enough but I can't seem to get it to work.

It compiles but I get this as my output:

```
0023F908-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-8
58993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-8
58993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-8589934600023F908-858993460-858993460-858
993460-858993460-858993460The largest value is 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

This is what the file contains:

```
4 5

3 1 4 1 5

2 3 6 7 1 

7 8 8 8 8 

9 8 7 6 5
```

And here's what I have so far:

```
void printValue( const ChartType, int, int);

int main () 
{ 
 ChartType chart; 
 int rowsUsed; 
 int colsUsed; 
 ifstream dataIn; 
 dataIn.open("Chart.txt"); 
 GetChart(dataIn, chart, rowsUsed, colsUsed); 
 PrintChart(chart, rowsUsed, colsUsed); 
 printValue(chart, rowsUsed, colsUsed);
 return 0; 
} 

void GetChart(ifstream& data, ChartType chart, int& rowsUsed, int& colsUsed) 
{ 
int tempVariable;
 data >> rowsUsed >> colsUsed; 
 for (int row = 0; row < rowsUsed; row++) 
    for (int col = 0; col < colsUsed; col++) 
        data >> chart[4][5];
        data >> tempVariable;
        chart[rowsUsed][colsUsed] = tempVariable;
 } 

void PrintChart( const ChartType chart, int rowsUsed, int colsUsed) 
{ 
 cout << chart[rowsUsed];
 for (int row = 0; row < rowsUsed; row++) 
 { 
 for (int col = 0; col < colsUsed; col++) 
 cout << chart[row][col]; 
 } 
}

 void printValue( const ChartType chart, int rowsUsed, int colsUsed) 
{ 
 int largest = 0;
 int row = 0;
 int col = 0;
 cout << chart[rowsUsed];
 for ( ; row < rowsUsed; row++) 
 { 
 for ( ; col < colsUsed; col++) 
 cout << chart[row][col];

 if (chart[row][col] > largest)
     largest = chart[row][col];
 }
 cout << "The largest value is " << largest << endl;
 }
```

Comment: You should also add why it _doesn't work_ ? I mean what does it give as the output?

Comment: oops, sorry! it's my first time on here. Thank you!

Comment: No harm done. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @user3064666 does file exists? Does stream can open it? You must check it by calling [`bool std::basic_ios::good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) before reading from it. Also show us `ChartType` definition

Comment: `data >> chart[4][5];` ???  Also, for loops only affect the following statement unless `{` and `}` surround multiple statements, so `data >> tempVariable;` and `chart[rowsUsed][colsUsed] = tempVariable;` run after the `for` loop has completed.  You may have tried to copy into `chart[row][col]` and got a compiler error... that would be because `row` and `col` only exist in their `for` loops' scopes.

Comment: It would help to see how `ChartType` is defined for the best shot of getting a proper answer in case what's already been mentioned doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The `GetChart` function is wrong, as I understand.
Try this,

```
void GetChart(ifstream& data, ChartType chart, int& rowsUsed, int& colsUsed) 
{ 
    data >> rowsUsed >> colsUsed; 
    for (int row=0; row<rowsUsed; ++row) 
        for (int col=0; col<colsUsed; ++col) 
            data >> chart[row][col];
}
```

Comment: +1 for a step in the right direction, but given `rowsUsed` and `colsUsed` were only just read, there's been no explicit resizing of `chart` to ensure it's large enough for the indixing done at `chart[row][col]`.  We can't know what's needed without seeing the implementation of `ChartType` (there's a very small chance its `operator[]` resizes automatically).

Comment: You could skip the temp variable and just do `data >> chart[row][col]`.